# How to configurate my ckeditor for correct display image

Tags: python, ckeditor, jinja2, ckeditor4.x

the picture climbs out of the div
and when i open site on mobile divice pictures show no correct

```
 <p class="lead">{{ post.text | safe }}</p>
```

[problem on mobile divice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxuGq.png),
[big screen problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Jqe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit `contents.css` in CKEditor's top-level folder. (Same folder as `ckeditor.js`)

Go to the bottom of the file and add whatever CSS code you like to enforce max widths and responsive behavior. e.g.

```css
p.lead img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you need further help on this, I recommend adding the tag `css` to your question.